# How to determine the dual space of se(2)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

In an article there are the following sentences:

The euclidean group $SE(2)=\left\{\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\v & R\end{array}\right]:v\in \mathbf{R}^{2\times1}\text{ and }R\in SO(2)\right\}$ is a real three dimensional conected matrix Lie group and its associated Lie alegbra is given by
$$se(2)=\left\{\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\\x_1 & 0 & -x_3\\x_2 & x_3 & 0\end{array}\right]:x_1,x_2,x_3\in \mathbf{R}\right\}.$$
The author identify the dual space $se(2)^*$ with matrices of the form
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & p_1 & p_2\\0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}p_3\\0 & -\frac{1}{2}p_3 & 0\end{array}\right].$$

My question is: how did he "identify" this?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to give us the title and author of the article...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mathoverflow.net, I found a description of the duality pairing between a Lie Algebra and its dual, namely $\langle X, \alpha \rangle = trace(X\alpha)$ where $X$ is in the algebra and $\alpha$ is in the dual.

But before going into that, let's talk about dual spaces a little. The dual of a vector space $V$ is the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $\mathbb R$, with addition being "addition of functions" and scalar multiplication being "multiply the function by a constant." Page 16 of http://www.tufts.edu/~fgonzale/lie.algebras.book.pdf gives a rather nice and concise description of the dual of a map, which amounts to this: if $T: V \rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation whose matrix with respect to some bases of $V$ and $W$ is $A$, then you can build $T^{*} : W^{*} \rightarrow V^{*}$, and build the matrix $B$ for *that* with respect to the dual bases of $V^{*}$ and $W^{*}$. Turns out that $B$ is just the transpose of $A$. (If $v_1, \ldots , v_n$ is a basis for $V$, the "dual basis" is $\phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots \phi_n$, where $\phi_i(v_j)$ is zero unless $i = j$, in which case it's $1$.) End of dual space discussion.

So you've got $se(3)$, consisting of a bunch of matrices, which can be regarded as representing linear maps $\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ with respect to the standard basis. The duals of these maps, expressed with respect to the standard dual basis, consist of the *transposes* of these matrices. These transposes are matrices of the form 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & a_1 & a_2\\0 & 0 & a_3\\0 & -a_3 & 0\end{array}\right]
$$

That's *almost* what your author wrote, except that there's the factor of $1/2$. Let's see if we can make sense of that. That's where the "trace pairing" above comes in.

If you look at matrices in $se(2)$ as you've described them above, and put in $x_1 = 1, x_2 = x_3 = 0$ to get a matrix $X_1$, you find that putting in $p_1 = 1, p_2 = p_3 = 0$ gives you a matrix $\alpha_1$ with $tr(X_1 \alpha_1) = 1$. You can similarly build $X_2, X_3$ and $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$, with the property that $tr(X_i \alpha_j) = 0$ unless $i = j$, and $tr(X_i \alpha_i) = 1$,  i.e., the $\alpha_j$s form a dual basis to the $X_i$s.

Once you're given the $X_i$s (as the author provided) and you know that the pairing is given by "trace-of-the-product", finding the dual basis amounts to finding some vectors (the columns of the $\alpha_j$s) that are perpendicular to certain rows certain $X_i$s so that the traces come out right, and making sure that the matrices you find are actually elements of the dual algebra (whose definition I don't have).

Let me go ahead and make this explicit. A basis for the Lie Algebra is 
$$
X_1 =  \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right]\\
X_2 =  \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right]\\
X_3 =  \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1\\0 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right]
$$

To find $\alpha_1$, you're looking for a matrix, of the form I described above, whose pairings with $X_2$ and $X_3$ both yield $0$. So let's write 
$$
\alpha_1 =  \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0 & b & c\\ 0 & 0& f\\0 &-f &0\end{array}\right]\\
$$
and compute the entries of $X_2 \alpha_1$:
$$
X_2\alpha_1 =  \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0& 0 & 0\\0&0& 0\\0 & b &c\end{array}\right]\\
$$
The trace of this is just $c$, so $c = 0$. Similarly, we find that $X_3 \alpha_1$ is 
$$
X_3\alpha_1 =  \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0& 0 & 0\\0&f& 0\\0 & 0 &f\end{array}\right]\\
$$
whose trace is $2f$, from which we conclude that $f$ = 0.

Finally, look at $X_1 \alpha_1$. That's 
$$
X_1\alpha_1 =  \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0& 0 & 0\\0&b& c\\0 & 0 &0\end{array}\right]\\
$$
whose trace is supposed to be $1$, so $b = 1$. So $\alpha_1$ must be

$$
\alpha_1 =  \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0& 1 & 0\\0&0& 0\\0 &0 &0\end{array}\right]\\
$$

Essentially the same analysis shows that $\alpha_2$ must be
$$
\alpha_2 =  \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0& 0 & 1\\0&0& 0\\0 &0 &0\end{array}\right]\\
$$
and $\alpha_3$ must be (because this time, the trace, $2f$, must equal 1)
$$
\alpha_3 =  \left[\begin{array}{ccc}0& 0 & 0\\0&0& \frac{1}{2}\\0 &-\frac{1}{2} &0\end{array}\right]\\
$$

Taking the linear combination $p_1 \alpha_1 + p_2 \alpha_2 + p_3 \alpha_3$ gives the expression that your author wrote.

Comment: thank you very much. You just give me an excellent mathematics lesson.